# Connect to mySQL with VB.NET from values

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im trying to connect to mySql, but I have problem locating where im doing wrong.

My form contain e a label that is a number thats going to be posted to `Score` and a textbox where the user typed their name to be posted in `Navn`.

My code so far is:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim connect As New SqlConnection("Data Source = mysqlAdress;Network Library= DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**;Password=**;")
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO 2048 VALUES(@score, @name)"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connect)

        command.Parameters.Add("@score", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label1.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        connect.Open()
        connect.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table name should be enclosed in backticks like this:

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO `2048` VALUES(@score, @name)"
```

Also try to avoid table names with such naming conventions ie., only numbers.

Also you are opening and closing the connection simultaneously.

```
connect.Open()
connect.Close()
```

Try like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = mysqlAdress;Network Library= DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**;Password=**;"
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO `2048` VALUES(@score, @name)"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", Label1.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox ex.Message.ToString
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using 
End Sub
```

Comment: My script keep shutting down at connect.Open()

Comment: `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlException` comes as "not defined"

Comment: @Eyrik:- have u added the reference of the MySql.Data ? The  MySql.dll file should be present in bin or in reference of your project. And then try to add at the top of your page `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Comment: Yes i did. Just read it wrong, it was the `Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)` part that was the issue. "Cant be converted to string"

Comment: No. The "Cant be converted to string" is breaking the script.

Comment: Check what? Cant se any changes

Comment: @Eyrik:- Check the connection string declaration. Now it is defined as string. `Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = mysqlAdress;Network Library= DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**;Password=**;"`

Comment: `Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)` causes `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll `

Comment: @Eyrik:- Your connection string is not correct. You need to check your connection string. You can try to provide like this" `Dim connectionString As String = "Server=ServerName; Uid=yourUID; Pwd=yourPassword; Database=DBName"`

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If i would like to add these data to a listbox from the mySql later, how would i go on with it?

Comment: @Eyrik:- Thats a seperate question, you can ask a new question with what you have tried, so as to get more attention.!